# Slow down div background image scrolling when it reaches top of window

Tags: jquery

Once a div reaches the top of the window, I'd like the div's background image to scroll slower than the content inside the div. I can't find an example online off hand that does specifically what I'm talking about.

I'm assuming this can be done with jQuery, but I'm not great with jQuery so I don't know exactly what it would entail.

Comment: Can you show us some code that you have tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I've just looked around for the exact effect I'm describing and can't find it. I'm primarily asking if it's possible to do something like that with jQuery. Like I said, I'm not good with jQuery so I don't know how I would even go about it. I just know that people use jQuery to do things that might be considered similar to what I'm asking about.

Comment: I once used a parallax plugin to scroll backgrounds at a different ratio than the window did. The content scrolls 1:1 with the window but the various background images scroll faster or slower and up or down, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want. This is the website: http://www.stationx.ca

Edit; also yes this site is gigantic blame the designer

Comment: Right. It would be something kind of similar to a normal parallax effect, except the div's background image would scroll along with the div normally until it got to the top of the window. Then it would start the "parallaxiness."

Comment: you might be able to achieve that with this plugin, but sadly I can't tell you how that would be accomplished: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ I don't know of one myself that specifically does what you describe out of the box.

Comment: I did what I was looking for without using any plugins. I almost feel like a real jQuery user now...almost. I just have to figure out how to bind it to each div in a particular class individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together code that accomplishes the task I wanted it to.

Here's my html:

```
    <div class="post" id="post-1">

        <div class="post-background" id="post-background-1"> </div>  

        <div class="post-content" id="post-content-1"  ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="post" id="post-2">

        <div class="post-background" id="post-background-2"> </div>  

        <div class="post-content" id="post-content-2"  ></div>

    </div>

    <div class="post" id="post-3">

        <div class="post-background" id="post-background-3"> </div>  

        <div class="post-content" id="post-content-3" ></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
 .post {position:relative;}
 .post-background {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%}
 .post-content {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = jQuery('.post').offset().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();;
    if (top < 0){
        var target = jQuery('.post').attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/);
        jQuery('#post-background-' + target +'').css( {
            'top' : (top/2.5)+"px", 'position' : 'fixed'
        });
    }
    if (top > 0){
        var target = jQuery('.post').attr('id').match(/[\d]+$/);
        jQuery('#post-background-' + target +'').css( {
            'top' : "0px", 'position' : 'absolute'
        });
    } 
});
```